# makemigrations isn't working- how to fix it?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, docker

I have a dockerized django project. I'm trying to make migrations, but I keep getting this error. What does this mean, and how can I fix it? I am really new to this, so please be as detailed as possible! Thank you

```
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/jasminedogu/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/jasminedogu/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/jasminedogu/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/jasminedogu/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/jasminedogu/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jasminedogu/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 101, in handle
    loader.check_consistent_history(connection)
  File "/Users/jasminedogu/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 283, in check_consistent_history
    applied = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/Users/jasminedogu/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 76, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "/Users/jasminedogu/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 56, in has_table
    return self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor())
  File "/Users/jasminedogu/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jasminedogu/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 260, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/Users/jasminedogu/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 236, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/Users/jasminedogu/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jasminedogu/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 220, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/Users/jasminedogu/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/Users/jasminedogu/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 220, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/Users/jasminedogu/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jasminedogu/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 197, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/Users/jasminedogu/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jasminedogu/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 185, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/Users/jasminedogu/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 127, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Comment: You don't have a connection to the database, check how your exposing connecting the ports with docker.

Comment: I ran "cat april7.sql | docker exec -i tcf_db psql -U tcf_django tcf_db" a few times, so it should be connected to the database? Its still not working

Comment: How are you exposing the port to the application?

Comment: How are you telling the application how to connect to the database?  How are you running the database?

Answer (score 0):

Your Django application is not connecting to the database.

Couple of things to check.
What port is your database running on and what is the hostname? If you're using docker-compose, the host will be the same as the database service name.

Next, check your settings.py insuring that your database is using the correct host and port. By default, on Postgres, Django will use port 5432. If this is not the case, update it.

Similarly, if you have not explicitly set a host, Django will use localhost. You will need to change this value to whatever your database service name is.